# Unclassifiable statement when calling a specific function

Tags: compilation, fortran

I want to add a function to my code that will calculate some variable. I created a dummy function

```
  double precision FUNCTION rawSE(x)
  double precision x
  real ax
  rawSE = 0.0d0
  return
  END
```

And I call it using

```
  selfE=rawSE(1.0d0)
```

When I try to compile the code, I get the error in the title. When I replace the rawSE with a value (1.0d0) I don't get an error. When I replace it with another function, I don't get an error. I copied a function that work properly and renamed it. I get the error.

So... what is going on here? This is not a column position issue (at least not a simple one) as they are all start on the same line.

How to resolve this?

Comment: I suggest that you show us more code, such as the code that is calling this function and the related declarations.    As stated in the comment below, it is good practice to include your procedures in modules and use them so that the interfaces can be checked.  Removing this function from the module could be more hiding the problem than fixing it.

Comment: @M.S.B. This is the line. I call this function once and I use it only to keep the flow of the code logical. I call this line outside of any loop. As I mentioned in my answer below, the solution was to move the declaration of rawSE outside of the module.

Comment: Do you have a conflicting declaration of rawSE?  Such as declaring it `external` or its type `double precision` in the program that uses it?  Just trying to guess something...  What compiler are you using?

Comment: I do declare it as double precision in my code. This is how I declare other functions as well. I use f95 compiler gcc version is 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

The rawSE function was declared in a module and a value was expected instead of a function. Moving the declaration out of the module part solved this.

Comment: But, if you import the module, you should be able to access your rawSE function. If possible, one should rather try to move things into a module, instead of moving them out of a module, as for example the compiler can check the correct calling only for module procedures...

Comment: @BálintAradi This is my logic but I it didn't work. What else might have significance in that manner?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more code. Do you have some minimal self containing example demonstrating the issue?

Comment: I'll try and generate one. It will take me some time though.

Answer (score 0):

I asked whether you declared `rawSE` in the program that uses it, and you replied that you declared it as `double precision`.  Do you mean that you declare the function both in the module and in the program that uses the module?   Like this?

```
module my_stuff

implicit none

contains

double precision FUNCTION rawSE(x)
  double precision x
  rawSE = 2.0d0 * x
  return
end FUNCTION rawSE

end module my_stuff


program test_rawSE

use my_stuff

implicit none

double precision rawSE   ! <-- This line

write (*, *) rawSE (2.0d0)

end program test_rawSE
```

If so, that is the problem.  You should declare the function once, so the line "This line" should be removed.  It is better to keep the module because that makes the interface explicit to the compiler.  Not only does it "know" that that the function return is double precision, it also "knows" that the function has a single double-precision argument.  This enables it to check the arguments of calls for consistency with these properties.

P.S.  gfortran 4.1 is really old and out of date.  More recent versions are much improved.  That might be why the error message is cryptic.  gfortran 4.7 identifies that two statements conflict with each other:

```
double precision rawSE
                      1
rawSE.f90:18.4:

use my_stuff
    2
Error: Symbol 'rawse' at (1) conflicts with symbol from module 'my_stuff', use-associated at (2)
```

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/p0KpSBiF) is more similar to what I have in my code. I  assume that my notation is discourage to say the least. I can't update the compiler on my server due to the old programmers approach "don't fix if it ain't borken". Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Yotam: That code should work if you add `external rawSE` to the module, or if you put the `double precision rawSE` declaration in your `program` instead. Either way, external procedures are very F77 style and do not really make use of the features of modules. The policy with respect to compilers is remarkable, since it precludes you from using any of the newer features supported as long as gfortran 4.1 does not "break", even though the newest compilers still work with F77 code.